# How to use aws lambda to call another lambda with user credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have 2 lambda written in difference language on aws lambda server

Suppose it called `C` and `J`

And there is a logic that, when user call `C` with parameter match some condition. It would do something and then invoke `J` like user have call `J` by themselves (same cognitoId)

So I need to get credentials of the user who call my `C` lambda function and use it to invoke `J`

But I can't find a clue of where I can get current user's credential from lambda environment

I can only get `context.Identity` but that not enough to create credentials for invoke lambda as imitated user

What could I do?

Comment: Check the environment variables set in the AWS Lambda process

Comment: @Leon There are `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` but did that came from cognito? I just think that it came from my own amazon IAM credentials, isn't it?

Comment: @Leon or is it will be overridden if function called from cognito?

Comment: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` correspond to the credentials that were used to invoke the lambda function.

Comment: @Leon I have test it with writing lambda to return { env,context } as payload. Call it with cognito credential. Then changing credentials with env returned and call the same function again. And no, the first call context has cognito but second call has no cognito

Comment: What's kicking off your initial Lambda function? How did the initial function get the cognito id?

Comment: @Vladimir Sorry for the late. The kicking is the client side calling lambda.invoke with cognito credential from STS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only workaround I could use now is, using DeveloperCredential to always get access token for each user and call subsequence lambda with that credential. The downside is all the user can't be anonymous user

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use examples from the Java SDK but these methods are available in all the SDKs so adapt to your language of choice.

You can use the [`AmazonCognitoClient`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidentity/AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.html#AmazonCognitoIdentityClient) to exchange the identityId token for a Credential (basically a temporary access key / secret key) using the method:

```
public GetCredentialsForIdentityResult getCredentialsForIdentity(GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest getCredentialsForIdentityRequest)
```

[`GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidentity/model/GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest.html) takes an identityId which can be exchanged for a [`GetCredentialsForIdentityResult`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidentity/model/GetCredentialsForIdentityResult.html). You can use `getCredentials()` on the result to get a [`Credentials`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidentity/model/Credentials.html) instance which you can then use to Invoke Lambda J.

Comment: Sadly that I tried getCredentialsForIdentity but that cannot work with authenticated identity with identityId alone, it need logins even it called from admin credentials